# react-navigation re-render view with back button

Tags: android, api, react-native, react-navigation, back-button

I'm using react-navigation module for navigation in react-native project.I want to call `componentWillMount()` again when back button is pressed.
**My router.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TabNavigator ,StackNavigator ,NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';


import Login from '../Login/Login';
import SignUp from '../Registration/SignUp';
import Charity from '../Registration/Charity';
import FetchFriend from '../Registration/FetchFriend';
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Paypal from '../Registration/Paypal';
import ForgetPassword from '../Registration/ForgetPassword';
import AddFriend from '../AddFriend/AddFriend';
import Upcomings from '../Upcomings/Upcomings';
const Routes =   {
  RECECNT: { screen : Upcomings,navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Recent Birthdays'
    }},
  UPNEXT : { screen : Upcomings,navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "Up Next"
    }},
  UPCOMING :{ screen : Upcomings,navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: "Upcoming Birthays"
    }},
};

const TabConfig = {
  stateName: 'MainNavigation',
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  animationEnabled: true,
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#DC6361',
    inactiveTintColor: 'black',
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 10,
      width: '100%',
    },style: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderTopColor: 'gray',
  }
  },
};
// register all screens of the app (including internal ones)
export const screenRoute = (SignIn) => {
  return StackNavigator({
    LOG_IN:{screen:Login},
    SIGN_UP:{screen:SignUp},
    CHARITY:{screen:Charity},
    FETCH_FRIEND:{screen:FetchFriend},
    DASHBOARD:{screen: Dashboard},
    PAYPAL:{screen: Paypal},
    FPASSWORD:{screen: ForgetPassword},
    ADDFRIEND:{screen: AddFriend},
    UPCOMINGS : {screen :TabNavigator(Routes, TabConfig)},
    },{
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode:'modal',
    initialRouteName: SignIn ? 'DASHBOARD':'LOG_IN'
  });
};
```

I fill a form and submit it, then navigate to another screen, Now if i press the Back Button of the android device it goes to the old screen with filled data.
I want an API call then state data to reset on back button press.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `goBack` action you can use `reset` action in React-Navigation it allows you to reset the navigation stack which re-renders the top most component again, this will solve your problem of state not getting reset.

To use `reset` action you need to redefine all the screens that you want in the navigation stack and the index of active screen.
Here is the example:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile'})
  ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

where `index` is the position of the screen that you want to be active and all the other screen is `actions` array will be pushed in the stack.

Here is the reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Reset

Other alternative is to use the callback, I don't know much of it as I have not implemented it but for reference you can go to the following links

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/733

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/845